# I want to use date recursively but not able to get the expected result

Tags: plsql

```
 WITH CTE_Dates(seqno,                                                          
 account_no,                                                                    
 subacc_no,                                                                     
 date1,                                                                         
 input_date,                                                                    
 act_date,                                                                      
 arrears_os) AS                                                                 
  (SELECT seqno,                                                                
          account_no,                                                           
          subacc_no,                                                            
          date1,                                                                
          TO_DATE('22-JUN-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY') input_date,                     
          (ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('22-JUN-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), -1) + 1) act_date, 
          arrears_os                                                            
     FROM det pd, ele pe                                                        
    WHERE pd.account_no = pe.account_no                                         
   UNION ALL                                                                    
   SELECT seqno,                                                                
          account_no,                                                           
          subacc_no,                                                            
          date1,                                                                
          TO_DATE('22-JUN-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY') input_date,                     
          (ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('22-JUN-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), -1) + 1) act_date, 
          arrears_os                                                            
     FROM CTE_Dates                                                             
    WHERE ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(input_date, 'MONTH'), 1) <=                          
          TO_DATE('22-JUN-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY')                                 

   )                                                                            
 SELECT seqno,                                                                  
        account_no,                                                             
        subacc_no,                                                              
        date1,                                                                  
        input_date,                                                             
        act_date,                                                               
        arrears_os,                                                             
        CASE                                                                    
          WHEN date1 BETWEEN act_date AND input_date THEN                       
           input_date                                                           
          ELSE                                                                  
           (ADD_MONTHS(input_date, -1))                                         
        END new_input_dt                                                        
   from CTE_Dates                                                               
  ORDER BY date1 DESC
```

**INPUT:**

```
   +----+----------+-------+-------------+---+------------+-----+
   |    |    A     |   B   |      C      | D |     E      |  F  |
   +----+----------+-------+-------------+---+------------+-----+
   |  1 | Current  |       |             |   |            |     |
   |  2 | 0        | seqno | subacc_no   |   | date1      |     |
   |  3 | 1        | 709   |     M223355 | 1 | 21/06/2019 |     |
   |  4 | 2        | 709   |     M223355 | 1 | 7/6/2019   |     |
   |  5 | 3        | 709   |     M223355 | 1 | 24/05/2019 |     |
   |  6 | 4        | 709   |     M223355 | 1 | 10/5/2019  |     |
   |  7 | 5        | 709   |     M223355 | 1 | 26/04/2019 |     |
   |  8 | 6        | 709   |     M223355 | 1 | 12/4/2019  |     |
   |  9 | 7        | 709   |     M223355 | 1 | 29/03/2019 |     |
   | 10 | 8        | 709   |     M223355 | 1 | 15/03/2019 |     |
   +----+----------+-------+-------------+---+------------+-----+
```

I want to use my given date recursively(less than 1 month ) and I have written above query based on mentioned input to achieve below output.  
I am giving input date '22-Jun-2019' want to continue iteration until date1 (24-MAY-2019) then iteration 2 should be start from '23-may-2019 and continue this iteration till date1 (26-APR-2019)and so on for iteration 3 and 4.

- want to consider 1 month (21/06/2019,7/6/2019,24/05/2019
- want to consider 2 month (10/5/2019,26/04/2019)
- want to consider 3 month (12/4/2019,29/03/2019)
- want to consider 4 month (15/03/2019)

**Expected Output**:

```
+---+-------+-------------+---+--------------+----------------+------------+-----+-------------+ 
|   |   A   |      B      | C |      D       |       E        |     F      |  G  |      H      | 
+---+-------+-------------+---+--------------+----------------+------------+-----+-------------+ 
| 1 | seqno | subacc_no   |   | date1        |     input_date | act_date   | amt |  rank/group | 
| 2 | 709   |     M223355 | 1 |   21/06/2019 | 22/06/2019     | 23/05/2019 | 200 |   1         | 
| 3 | 709   |     M223355 | 1 |   7/6/2019   |     22/06/2019 | 23/05/2019 | 200 |   1         | 
| 4 | 709   |     M223355 | 1 |   24/05/2019 | 22/06/2019     | 23/05/2019 | 200 |   1         | 
| 5 | 709   |     M223355 | 1 |   10/5/2019  |     22/05/2019 | 23/04/2019 | 200 |   2         | 
| 6 | 709   |     M223355 | 1 |   26/04/2019 | 22/05/2019     | 23/04/2019 | 200 |   2         | 
| 7 | 709   |     M223355 | 1 |   12/4/2019  |     22/04/2019 | 23/03/2019 | 200 |   3         | 
| 8 | 709   |     M223355 | 1 |   29/03/2019 | 22/04/2019     | 23/03/2019 | 200 |   3         | 
| 9 | 709   |     M223355 | 1 |   15/03/2019 | 22/03/2019     | 23/02/2019 | 200 |   4         | 
+---+-------+-------------+---+--------------+----------------+------------+-----+-------------+
```

Comment: Please put an effort to your question, not just do copy and paste. Show what you did and ask your question clearly. The community here will not do your homework.

Comment: See [ask]. Format your code, use [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/), do not post images, put expected results in the question (update the question if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

First off you are still missing table definitions (DDL), columns headings on input output do not define the the tables. Further, you have a consistency issue. Your query refers to account_number but neither your sample data nor your output does so. Also your query joins tables det and ele, but neither is mentioned in the description.

Finally your expected output contains 2 columns (amt,rank/group), but neither exists in the input, so they cannot be output. But then neither you query does not contain them either. Lacking any real table descriptions I made my own.

```
create table det (
       seqno       integer,                                                                
       account_no  integer,                                                           
       subacc_no   varchar(20),
       d           integer,                                                            
       date1       date ,                                                                
       arrears_os  varchar2(20)
     );

insert into det(seqno, account_no, subacc_no,d,date1)
   select  1, 709, 'M223355', 1, to_date('21/06/2019', 'FMdd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
   select  2, 709, 'M223355', 1, to_date('07/06/2019', 'FMdd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
   select  3, 709, 'M223355', 1, to_date('24/05/2019', 'FMdd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
   select  4, 709, 'M223355', 1, to_date('10/05/2019', 'FMdd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
   select  5, 709, 'M223355', 1, to_date('26/04/2019', 'FMdd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
   select  6, 709, 'M223355', 1, to_date('12/04/2019', 'FMdd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
   select  7, 709, 'M223355', 1, to_date('29/03/2019', 'FMdd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
   select  8, 709, 'M223355', 1, to_date('15/03/2019', 'FMdd/mm/yyyy') from dual ; 

create table ele as
  select distinct account_no from det;
```

Your description of what you want needs more information. You say you are given the date 22-Jun-2019 the iterate back to 24-May-2019, is that iteration by Day or by Month. Second iteration begins 23-May-2019 and end at 26-Apr?

Then you want to consider months: 1 month but you list 3 (I think I may have dropped 1); 2 months but list 3, 2 months but list 2, and 4 months but list 1. And the dates listed appear to be just random. At least I cannot find a pattern.

Now for the query. I will assume what you are trying in the description is:

1. Given an initial input date compute an active date as the prior
   month + 1 day (ie for 22-Jun-2019 produce 23-May-2019;
2. Iterate for a total of 4 cycles, on each iteration use the previously computed active date as the input date.

I don't know what your main query in attempting to do. You introduce a column (new_input_dt) which is not in your expected output and add 2 columns (ant, rank/group) to  output not in the query.
So, I'll return the same, but add to the cycle (cyc) you may need to filter on as you do not mention which of the iterations you are interested in. But the CTE should show you how to use a recursive CTE.

```
with cte_dates (account_no,input_date, act_date, cyc) as
     ( select account_no
            , to_date('22-JUN-2019', 'dd-mon-yyyy') input_date                     
            , (add_months(to_date('22-JUN-2019', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), -1) + 1) act_date
            , 1 cyc
         from ele
      union all 
      select account_no
           , act_date                    
           , add_months(act_date, -1) + 1  
           , cyc + 1
        from cte_dates           
       where cyc+1 <= 4                 
     )
select  pd.seqno,                                                                  
         pd.account_no,                                                             
         pd. subacc_no,  
         pd.d               -- D on input, C on output descriptions?                                                           
         pd. date1,                                                                  
         cte.input_date,                                                             
         cte.act_date,                                                               
         pd.arrears_os,                                                             
        case                                                                    
          when  pd.date1 between cte.act_date and cte.input_date
          then  cte.input_date                                                           
          else  add_months(cte.input_date, -1)                                         
        end new_input_dt,
        cte.cyc
   from cte_dates cte
   join det pd on (pd.account_no = cte.account_no) 
  order by date1 desc ;
```

Comment: It has been over a week now. If the answer solved you problem please accept it, if not then what is the remaining issue? Don't just leave questions hanging if needed delete and post a new question.

Comment: This looks very helpful, though I would say that it is better to write your answers for a general audience rather than just the OP. I've removed commentary relating to answer formatting, since that dilutes the material that readers most want to see.

Comment: In general if you think a question is not ready to answer, answer something else, or help the OP get their question answerable by adding comments. Formatting/voting commentary is very welcome there. Unfortunately most 1-rep users don't come back to interact with their helpers - you can send a quick reminder under the question if you want, but in my experience there isn't much point in doing so. You can see their last-signed-in timestamp in their profile.